# how to call jquery modal

Tags: jquery

I have an issue with how to call/display my modal when a link is click. Any idea on how to make this work?

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $('#dialog').hide();
        $('a.Temp').click(function(){
           $('#dialog').dialog({ 
                        modal: true,
                        //autoOpen: false,
                        bgiframe: false,
                        closeOnEscape: false,
                        title: "Test",
                        width: 520,
                        height: 360,
                        open: function(event, ui) { 
                                jQuery('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide();
                                $('#dialog').dialog('option', 'position', 'center'); },
                        buttons: [
                            {
                                text: "Cancel",
                                click: function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }
                            },
                            {
                                text: "Save"
                            }],
                        draggable: false });
        return false;

        });
     });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('a.Temp').click(function(){


        $('#dialog').dialog({ 
                        modal: true,
                        autoOpen: false,
                        bgiframe: false,
                        closeOnEscape: false,
                        title: "Test",
                        width: 520,
                        height: 360,
                        open: function(event, ui) { 
                                jQuery('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide();
                                $('#dialog').dialog('option', 'position', 'center'); },
                        buttons: [
                            {
                                text: "Cancel",
                                click: function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }
                            },
                            {
                                text: "Save"
                            }],
                        draggable: false });
        return false;

});
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but doesnt work. I had to add $('#dialog').hide(); ... even so, when I run it, the dialog shows/disappear quickly when I click on the link.

Comment: thanks ... but i found why this is happening. I had to add "e.preventDefault()" on the click function.